# Import Duty from Holland to UK For a Card Game

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, customs

I want to buy a card game (about 1000 cards or more) in one box from Holland. It is not a normal deck of cards, it is a game a bit like Magic, but not Magic. It is not boosters, or anything like that. It is one self contained game in one box.

I live in the UK. The game is in a shop in Holland.

Would there be any import duty on me as an individual purchasing this game. It costs about £67 including postage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would there be any import duty on me as an individual purchasing this game. It costs about £67 including postage.

Probably not:

> **Customs Duty**
>
> You’ll be charged Customs Duty on all goods sent from outside the UK (or the UK and the EU if you’re in Northern Ireland) if they’re either:
>
> - excise goods
> - worth more than £135
>
> If you’re charged Customs Duty, you’ll need to pay it on both:
>
> - the price paid for the goods
> - postage, packaging and insurance

https://www.gov.uk/goods-sent-from-abroad/tax-and-duty

Comment: But note that the supplier is required to register for and collect UK VAT, even though they’re not UK-based. Very many European suppliers can’t be bothered and so simply won’t ship to the UK.